# Is it possible to get country details from serialized data without unserialize?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

Is it possible to get country details from serialized content without unserialize ?

`a:11:{s:8:"newsFrom";s:0:"";s:7:"country";s:2:"IN";s:15:"state";s:0:"";s:16:"region";s:0:"";s:6:"awards";s:0:"";s:7:"website";s:0:"";s:8:"facebook";s:0:"";s:7:"twitter";s:0:"";s:8:"linkedin";s:0:"";s:10:"googleplus";s:0:"";s:9:"short_bio";s:0:"";}`

Comment: Why would you not want to unserialize?

Comment: Of course you can do some string manipulation/regex magic yourself – but _why_? It is likely to introduce errors in edge cases that you did not think about, where as unserializing will give you a definitive result. This seems to be a question of the “I have a hammer, but what _other_ tools could I use to drive this nail into the wall?” variety …

Comment: Yuck. Just use unserialize.

Comment: unserialize is an easy way. but any other option. "simply to know"

Comment: you can use regex,explode etc. there are many ways but unserialize is the best.